# Modify sql query to give distinct results

Tags: sql

How can I write the following query to return distinct results?

```
select
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (Order by LEN(a.code)),
    idno, date, time 
from 
    table
```

I need second column `idno` to be distnct...

Comment: Edit your question with sample data and expected output. It is not clear from the question what you are trying to do. Also, tag the question with the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guess. It's only a guess because you've left out loads of vital information, like what do you do with the field `date`? MAX? MIN? Does the rownumber have to be dense?

```
SELECT idno, 
       Max(date) date, 
       Max(time) time, 
       Row_number () 
         OVER ( 
           ORDER BY Max(Len(code))), 
FROM   table 
GROUP  BY idno
```